# How do you get the text part of a label in another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a program that has to open a file and depending on the info in that file it has to open another file. I have to label that make up the other file's name.  Form a another class I'm trying to read the text part of the label.

In the Class I have tried

```
Form1 frm1 = new frm1();
Name = (frm1.label1.Text + frm1.Label2.text);
```

I have also tried
in The Class

```
Form1 frm1 = new frm1();
name = (frm1.sendText + ".txt");
```

on the form

```
public string sendText
{
   return (Label1.Text + Label2.Text);
}
```

I keep getting back can't find .txt.
It's like my labels text fields are blank when they're not.

Comment: You're creating a *new instance* for `Form1`, never showing it, and then looking for the values it contains.  Which will be empty by default.  You need to get the values from the instance of `Form1` that you are showing.

Comment: How do I do that because when I say Form1.label1.Text it give me an error saying An object reference is required for a non-static field, method, or property.

Comment: an instance of a form with type `Form1` must already be on screen by the time your code executes. You need to address that form. Do you have both `Form1` and `frm1` types?

Comment: @user3543447 Please post your code that shows `Form1`, I'm guessing it's your `Program.Main` method.

Comment: @user3543447 Also you really should **name your controls**. `Form1` and `label1` are not descriptive identifiers.

Comment: @user3543447: Where is an instance of `Form1` ever created/shown on the screen?  How do you get from there to the code where you're currently creating a new instance of `Form1`?  Don't just try to refer to properties statically.  You have an existing instance of `Form1` somewhere, that's what is shown on the screen.  You need to get *that instance's* data.  It's possible that instance is created by default in `Program.cs`, but if so then what form are you calling this code from and how is *that* form created/shown?

Comment: @user3543447: Consider as an analogy... You get a car off of an assembly line, the model of the car is `Form1`.  You put your suitcase in the car's trunk and drive it for a little bit.  Then you walk back to the factory and get another car off of the assembly line.  Same exact model, same exact features, same everything.  On this new car you open the trunk and are surprised not to find your suitcase there.

Comment: Also, how does this even compile?  `Form1 frm1 = new frm1();`  Is your type called `Form1` or `frm1`?  Why are you naming a variable the same name as a type?  If this compiles at all it's really unnecessarily confusing, which is probably contributing to why you're misunderstanding something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Form1` class, you can add a public property that you can access to retrieve the value of both labels from outside the class.

```
public string LabelText
{
    get { return Label1.Text + Label2.Text; }
}
```

Then, in your other class, you can just use

```
string name = frm1.LabelText + ".txt";
```

As the comments above have said, it's important to make sure your reference to `Form1` references the same form that has the populated labels. One way is to pass this reference to your other class via its constructor:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    private Form1 form;

    public OtherClass(Form1 form)
    {
        this.form = form;
    }
}
```

You can then use this reference from within the class to access members of the form such as the property we just created.

Comment: Thank you this has helped alot